# Pulling a form name as a parameter

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

Let's say I have the following HTML form:

```
<form name="createnewuser" action="verifyInfo.jsp">
    ... Contents of form here ...
</form>
```

In verifyInfo.jsp, is there a way to call the form's name (ideally as some kind of ${param} variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the submitted form, you can use:

- A hidden input field.
- The name or value of the submit button.

The name of the form is not sent to the server as part of the POST data.

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="submit" name="form1" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="submit" name="form2" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
```

Now either form1 or form2 will be sent as POST data containing the value text of the button.

Here is some code. Im not familiar with JSP but I think this is what you do O_O

```
if ( request.getParameter("form1") != null ) {
     //Do stuff with form1
}
else if ( request.getParameter("form2") != null ) {
     //Do stuff with form2
}
```

Comment: I'm using the core library tags so no java conditionals, but close enough! Thanks for confirming my sneaking suspicion that that was not possible. I just couldn't find documentation of the fact anywhere online :)